# How to display all images from a particular internal directory in a Slider view?

Tags: android, slideshow, android-sliding

> I trying to display images from particular directory. Getting length
>   and image names and I could not able to display images.
>   I tried like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener{
SliderLayout sliderLayout;
HashMap<String,String> Hash_file_maps ;
ImageView Image_view;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    Hash_file_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sliderLayout = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider); 
    File file=new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/NC");
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    int count = 0;
    for (File f: list){
        String name = f.getName();
    if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") ||   name.endsWith(".png"))
```

> Hash_file_maps.put("",file.getName());

```
            count++;
    }
    for(String name : Hash_file_maps.keySet()){
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(Hash_file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle()
                .putString("extra",name);
        sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
    sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    sliderLayout.setDuration(10000);
    sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sliderLayout.stopAutoCycle();
    super.onStop();
}
```

> Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.Just replace this line

```
.image(Hash_file_maps.get(name))
```

with

```
.image(new File(Hash_file_maps.get(name)))
```